# Finding the highest value contiguous pixels in a raster

Tags: qgis

I have a raster of ~60,000 pixels, and each pixel has an integer value. I would like to find the ten contiguous pixels which sum to the greatest value. Ideally this would be achievable in QGIS.

I suspect that the number of possibilities means finding an exact solution may be impossible, and this will end up an exercise in image segmentation/object recognition to group high value pixels together

Can someone with more experience suggest whether this is possible or not?

Comment: So those 10 pixels can be in a row or as a group of 3x3 pixels + 1, all that matters is that they are contiguos? What if the pixels just touch at the corners?

Comment: Ideally it would be any contiguous configuration, so a row of ten would be fine, and also ideally diagonally-touching-at-the-corners would be allowed as contiguous. Thank you for asking for clarification.

Comment: Very interesting problem. Block of ((3x3)+1) is rather different than 10 diagonal pixels in a row. With blocks of 3x3 you could simply calculate an average and store that into the centre pixel. Heatmap/kernel density visualization does roughly the same thing  but averaging diagonal high score pixels surrounded by zeroes gives a low average value. With pixels in a row you could perhaps apply some routing algorithm and find route with highest cost. Probably you must use several methods together. I wish you good luck!